# Cartesian product without duplicates using select statement on table valued function returning equal number of rows

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, duplicates, cartesian-product

I'm not sure if the title properly describes my problem but here it goes..

I have a table valued function that takes in comma separated values.
I have two strings which will have same number of comma separated entries.

Following query returns me a Cartesian product

```
select * from dbo.SplitString('test,test1',',') as a,dbo.SplitString('45,78',',') as b
```

```
+-------+-------+  
| items | items |  
+-------+-------+  
| test  |  45   |  
| test  |  78   |  
| test1 |  45   |  
| test1 |  78   |  
+-------+-------+
```

I need a output with the corresponding values in a row with no duplicates like

```
+-------+-------+  
| items | items |  
+-------+-------+  
| test  |  45   |  
| test1 |  78   |  
+-------+-------+
```

Any thoughts on how I can get the above output using the select statement along with function only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible unless `SplitString` returns something that you can derive an order from (for example, it could return a column that is the index of the item).

SQL Server is set-based and sets do not have order. Order is specified only explicitly by ordering on a particular colums.

Add an `Index int not null` column to `SplitString` and join the results on the index together. Use the query from Jayvee's answer for that (but order by `Index`, not by `colx`). I'll copy the query:

```
--adapted from Jayvee's answer:
select a.colx, b.colx from 
(select colx, row_number() over(order by a.Index) rown from dbo.SplitString('test,test1',',')) a
join a
(select colx, row_number() over(order by b.Index) rown from dbo.SplitString('45,78',',')) b
on a.rown=b.rown
```

Comment: agree, ideally the function should return a correlation key to make the join always possible

Answer (score 1):

assuming a couple of things about your data and function this should work:

```
select a.colx, b.colx from 
(select colx, row_number() over(order by colx) rown from dbo.SplitString('test,test1',',')) a
join a
(select colx, row_number() over(order by colx) rown from dbo.SplitString('45,78',',')) b
on a.rown=b.rown
```

Comment: Doesn't work because the row_number's are not aligned. The items might get reordered.

Comment: true, this only works if the columns are related by order; another option could be (order by select(1))

Comment: That would mean "no order at all" and the results could be valid only by coincidence.